# How do I speed up iteration of large datasets in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a query set of approximately 1500 records from a Django ORM query.  I have used the select_related() and only() methods to make sure the query is tight.  I have also used connection.queries to make sure there is only this one query.  That is, I have made sure no extra queries are getting called on each iteration.

When I run the query cut and paste from connection.queries it runs in 0.02 seconds.  However, it takes seven seconds to iterate over those records and do nothing with them (pass).

What can I do to speed this up?  What causes this slowness?

Comment: You should include more details about your models and the query!

Comment: You also should write Django <-- this way :) he was a guitarist, not a DJ

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A QuerySet can get pretty heavy when it's full of model objects. In similar situations, I've used the .values method on the queryset to specify the properties I need as a list of dictionaries, which can be much faster to iterate over.

Django documentation: [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

Comment: You were right.  It turns out the instantiation of the model objects on each iteration was causing a lot of overhead.  Using the values method took the iteration of the set down from seven seconds, to just a few milliseconds.

Comment: Awesome. Glad I was able to help.

Comment: I noticed a huge performance increase with this! I was iterating a queryset of 110000 items, which took almost 70 seconds to complete. Iterating the same values_list took 5 seconds!

Answer (score 3):

1500 records is far from being a large dataset, and seven seconds is really too much. There is probably some problem in your models, you can easily check it by getting (as Brandon says) the values() query, and then create explicitly the 1500 object by iterating the dictionary. Just convert the ValuesQuerySet into a list before the construction to factor out the db connection.

Answer (score 2):

How are you iterating over each item:

```
items = SomeModel.objects.all()
```

Regular for loop on each

```
for item in items:
    print item
```

Or using the QuerySet [iterator](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#iterator)

```
for item in items.iterator():
    print item
```

According to the doc, the `iterator()` can improve performance.  The same applies while looping very large Python list or dictionaries, it's  best to use `iteritems()`.

Comment: Am not sure whether this would work, as mostly the iteration is done in the template and am not sure whether we have the .iterator() there.

Comment: I've checked it and it is actually working. Speed up the for loop a lot. From 0:00:45.550635 to 0:00:09.761178, so at least 4 times faster!!!

Answer (score 1):

Does your model's `Meta` declaration tell it to "order by" a field that is stored off in some other related table? If so, your attempt to iterate might be triggering 1,500 queries as Django runs off and grabs that field for each item, and then sorts them. Showing us your code would help us unravel the problem!