# Slow iteration over django queryset

Tags: django, optimization, django-models, iteration, django-queryset

I am iterating over a django queryset that contains anywhere from 500-1000 objects. The corresponding model/table has 7 fields in it as well. The problem is that it takes about 3 seconds to iterate over which seems way too long when considering all the other data processing that needs to be done in my application.

EDIT:
Here is my model:

```
    class Node(models.Model):
        node_id = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=30)
        jobs = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
        available_mem = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=30)
        assigned_mem = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True ,max_length=30)
        available_ncpus = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
        assigned_ncpus = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
        cluster = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=30)
        datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
```

This is my initial query, which is very fast:

```
    timestamp = models.Node.objects.order_by('-pk').filter(cluster=cluster)[0]
    self.nodes = models.Node.objects.filter(datetime=timestamp.datetime)
```

But then, I go to iterate and it takes 3 seconds, I've tried two ways as seen below:

```
    def jobs_by_node(self):
    """returns a dictionary containing keys that
       are strings of node ids and values that
       are lists of the jobs running on that node."""
    jobs_by_node = {}

    #iterate over nodes and populate jobs_by_node dictionary
    tstart = time.time()
    for node in self.nodes:
        pass #I have omitted the code because the slowdown is simply iteration
    tend = time.time()
    tfinal = tend-tstart
    return jobs_by_node
```

Other method:

```
    all_nodes = self.nodes.values('node_id')
    tstart = time.time()
    for node in all_nodes:
        pass
    tend = time.time()
    tfinal = tend-tstart
```

I tried the second method by referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656238/how-do-i-speed-up-iteration-of-large-datasets-in-django) post, but it still has not sped up my iteration one bit. I've scoured the web to no avail. Any help optimizing this process will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Note: I'm using Django version 1.5 and Python 2.7.3

Comment: The first question I have is are you running `DEBUG = True`? Second, I very much doubt the problem is with iteration, as I have used django in situation where iterating over a queryset that contained 250,000 objects without problem. The problem is most likely with whatever you are doing in the middle of your loop (the part where you put `pass`). In addition, if you are walking across foreign keys, it would speed up your code to use `select_related`, but again, without seeing more details its impossible to tell you what is the problem. Finally, don't use `pk` for ordering.

Comment: I am using DEBUG=True due to development, and I ran the timing with putting "pass" in the loop. The line that starts the for loop until tfinal (with pass being the only thing in the loop) takes 3 seconds. And that's why I'm so baffled, because it's not that large of a dataset. Thanks.

Comment: Don't time your code with `DEBUG=True`, it does many things behind the scenes with caching that will affect timing.

Comment: Ok, but if I perform the same operation via the shell and put "pass" in the forloop, I can see that it takes about the same amount of time. So, despite my incorrect timing method, it is still slow.

Comment: Its slow because you have `DEBUG=True`.

Comment: Ok, I'll test it out in the morning, thanks for the help.

Comment: Definitely didn't change the speed setting DEBUG=False. I'm going to try some different ways of querying, the only thing I can think is that my initial query is fast because of its lazy evaluation but then when I iterate, it's actually hitting the db being slow.

Comment: what is the database?

Comment: Postgres, it has about 1 million entries in the Node table alone so it's not really an iteration problem. It's that my query needs to be further optimized (IMHO). Thanks though, got me thinking more.

Answer (score 1):

Check the issued SQL query. You can use `print` statement:

```
print self.nodes.query  # in general: print queryset.query
```

That should give you something like:

```
SELECT id, jobs, ... FROM app_node
```

Then run `EXPLAIN SELECT id, jobs, ... FROM app_node` and you'll know what exactly is wrong.

---

Assuming that you know what the problem is after running EXPLAIN, and that simple solutions like adding indexes aren't enough, you can think about e.g. fetching the relevant rows to a separate table every X minutes (in a cron job or Celery task) and using that separate table in you application.

If you are using PostgreSQL you can also use [materialized views](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html) and "wrap" them in an [unmanaged Django model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#managed).

Comment: I'll try this out, but as I just commented above, I think it's because there are 1 million entries in the table and I'm filtering out 500-1000 of the more recent entries. I may just have one table for current data and a historical table that only needs to be queried sparingly in my application. All good suggestions and insight though. Appreciate the time and help. Thanks.

Comment: That's the whole point--EXPLAIN will tell you e.g. which index is missing, then you will be able to fix the problem.