# Speeding up iteration over a large QuerySet in Django

Tags: python, django, iteration, pythonanywhere

I'm trying my hand at the [Riot API challenge](https://developer.riotgames.com/discussion/riot-games-api/show/bX8Z86bm), and I'm trying to use Django as a backend hosted on [PythonAnywhere.com](http://PythonAnywhere.com).

I have setup a database which uses a structure similar to the one below

```
class MatchDetails(models.Model):
    # Data fields

class Participant(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(MatchDetails)
    # Data fields

class Timeline(models.Model):
    participant = models.ForeignKey(Participant)
    # Data fields

# More fields, most with MatchDetails as foreign key.
```

I have written a function which retrieves and stores data, and I now have almost 40 000 games stored, with 10 participants in each game. My goal is to extract some statistics from this data, and I basically do something like:

```
allMatches = MatchDetails.objects.all()
for m in allMatches:
    participants = m.participant_set.all()
    for p in participants:
        # Increment some values
# save the result to the database
```

Currently it takes a little more than 2 hours.

> 2015-04-11 03:47:35 -- Completed task, took 7942.00 seconds, return
>   code was 0.

This is a ridiculous amount of time, isn't it? Is there some way for me to speed it up?

I've tried to use iterator, and I also tried using .value_list and .all.values() to iterate over, but I am unable to get objects related through foreign key this way.

[How do I speed up iteration of a large dataset in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656238/how-do-i-speed-up-iteration-of-large-datasets-in-django)

Is there any way for me to access my foreign key objects when using value_list? Or is there anything else I can do to speed it up? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2):

The best optimization at this point is to use [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
allMatches = MatchDetails.objects.prefetch_related('participant_set')
for m in allMatches:
    for p in m.participant_set.all():
        # Increment some values
# save the result to the database
```

This reduces your number of queries from about 40 000 to 2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried using prefetch related based on your answer, but my data set then uses to much memory and my process gets killed. I'll try to write some iterator function myself, which can conserve memory and still use prefetch related.

Comment: It is still key to reduce the number of queries if you want reasonable performance. Depending on what statistics you need, Glenn's answer might be better.

Answer (score 1):

knbk's answer is great. You could also do your counting in the database. For instance, if you had a field on the participant model for time spent playing and you wanted the average time that participants spent playing, you could use something like

```
Participant.objects.all().aggregate(Avg('time_spent_playing'))
```

Have a look at the [Django aggregation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/) for more info.

Comment: Unfortunately prefetch related made the process use to much memory. I rewrote it to use aggragates and counts, and it now completed in 366 seconds, a considerable improvement. There was a few of the old metrics I was unable to extract with this method, but I'll just exclude them. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to speed it up using [prefetch related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

Also, in your values_list, you can get just the properties you need of your related objects traversing like "foreign_key_relation_name__attribute".

Using "iterator()" is also a good way of improving speed if you only iterate once through the queryset.

How is your "save the result to the database" code? If you save all items in batch with update() instead of saving each one by one, you will improve your speed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on two factors - what it is you're updating, and if you're running Django 1.8 - you don't have to iterate through everything.

```
from django.db.models import F
m.participant_set.update(some_field=F('some_field')*10)
```

This would update all `some_field` in the participants model to be its current value times ten which would be orders of magnitude faster than iterating over all the rows and doing an update per row.

Worth having in mind is that if you have overridden the Participant.save()-method, it won't be called, and save signals wont be sent either.